# Help with identifying connector for 25 AWG wire

Tags: connector, identification

I believe the wire here is 25 AWG. Does anybody know the name of this connector? I need the specification to write up a defect sheet and I currently cannot travel due to quarantine measures.

[image: photo showing connector and wiring]

Comment: It looks [like this?](http://sparks.gogo.co.nz/catalog/Wire-and-Connectors-37/Wire-169/Prewired-Wire-to-Wire-4-Wire-Connector-Pair-648.html) Or [this?](https://www.nooelec.com/store/jst-sm-connectors-4p.html)

Comment: how is the inability to travel relevant to the question?

Comment: I am not able to go to the site due to travel restrictions currently in force, I need the spec of this connector, I am working from home due to coronovirus travel restrictions.

Comment: Wire looks more like 26AWG. Odd AWG sizes are not that common.

Answer (score 2):

I would need pictures of the other side and measurements to verify, however it appears to be a JST [SMR-04V-B](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/SMR-04V-B/455-3247-ND/2137107) mating to a JST [SMP-04V-BC](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/SMP-04V-BC/455-3248-ND/7230521). Both can take a 22-28AWG wire.

Here is the Datasheet for the [SM Series](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSM.pdf) to verify.

[image][image]